# Rails admin showing error of fontawsome path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, font-awesome, rails-admin

Here are errors which are displayed in console during request to rails_admin:

> GET http://localhost:3333/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.woff?v=4.2.0 (anonymous function) @ jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1:3605jQuery.Callbacks.fire @ jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1:3144jQuery.Callbacks.self.fireWith @ jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1:3256jQuery.extend.ready @ jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1:3468completed @ jquery.self-d03a5518f45df77341bdbe6201ba3bfa547ebba8ed64f0ea56bfa5f96ea7c074.js?body=1:3499
>   company:1 GET http://localhost:3333/assets/fonts/fontawesome-webfont.ttf?v=4.2.0

Comment: Have you run `rails g rails_admin:install` after you did bundle install ? This will generate some additional files as well as put an entry to fontawesome in your `application` manifest.

Comment: @JensDebergh Thanks jens